# How to make a small Button in Python without Tkinter

Tags: python, button

in Python without using tkinter, can anyone help?
Here's the code i'd like to add it to:

```
import time

pswrd = '12345678'

while True:

 m = input("1.Login   2.Reset Password\n")
 
 if m == "1":
     
     n = input("Password:\n")

     if n == pswrd:
       print("Password Correct\n")
   
     else:
         print("Wrong Password\n")
     
 else:
     n = input("New Password:\n")
     pswrd = n
     repeat = 'While True'
```

Im starting to make some tests for an Os i want to build, i know, it's big of a goal but yeah... It just helps me train my newbie skills x)
Can anyone help with it plsss ?

Comment: Where do you want the button to be shown? As a child of what window? A button needs to be *somewhere*. Tkinter and other UI libraries give you a somewhere.

Comment: @Kemp just after the
if n == pswrd:
       print("Password Correct\n")

Comment: I mean literally visually on the screen, where should the button be shown? A terminal window can't show graphical buttons inline with the text, so where does the button appear? Where are you implementing the event loop to listen for the button being clicked? A lot of infrastructure goes into displaying and interacting with UI items.

Answer (score 0):

Use python Kivy or python pyQT.

Example:

Button with Kivy:

```
# import kivy module
import kivy

# this restrict the kivy version i.e
# below this kivy version you cannot
# use the app or software
kivy.require("1.9.1")

# base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
# app:always refers to the instance of your application
from kivy.app import App

# creates the button in kivy
# if not imported shows the error
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# class in which we are creating the button
class ButtonApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        # use a (r, g, b, a) tuple
        btn = Button(text ="Push Me !",
                font_size ="20sp",
                background_color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                color =(1, 1, 1, 1),
                size =(32, 32),
                size_hint =(.2, .2),
                pos =(300, 250))

        # bind() use to bind the button to function callback
        btn.bind(on_press = self.callback)
        return btn

    # callback function tells when button pressed
    def callback(self, event):
        print("button pressed")
        print('Yoooo !!!!!!!!!!!')
        

# creating the object root for ButtonApp() class
root = ButtonApp()

# run function runs the whole program
# i.e run() method which calls the target
# function passed to the constructor.
root.run()
```

Button with pQT:

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):

        # creating a push button
        button = QPushButton("CLICK", self)

        # setting geometry of button
        button.setGeometry(200, 150, 100, 30)

        # adding action to a button
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)

    # action method
    def clickme(self):

        # printing pressed
        print("pressed")

# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```